# C# action to an integer

Tags: c#, action

**thank you every body i finished my prodgram with Daniel Hilgarth help**

i dont know how explain what i want to ask so i will try to show you that,

i want a to be a number, lets say 5.

b to be a number , 3 for example , and M to be an action

and i want to write something like that:

```
if(c == 6)
{ 
    M = " * "; 
}
if(c == 7)
{ 
    M = "/";
}
if( a M b == 15)
{
    lable1.Text = " Hi";
}
```

the program says if c = 6 
M will be the multipacation action and a M b will be 5 * 3 = 15

please help me how to write it because i have no clue

**let me explain my self, i want to have a command line like if(a M b N c K d == 25) { lable1.Text = "hi"; } and a b c d are numbers that changes with 'for' and M N K are strings of Mathematical operation that also change with 'for' and every time the program checks if a M b N c K d == 25...**

Comment: See update to my answer.

Comment: if you're looking to write that specific syntax, I'm afraid that's impossible in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
Func<int, int, int> M = null;
if(c == 6)
{ 
    M = (x, y) => x * y; 
}
if(c == 7)
{ 
    M = (x, y) => x / y; 
}
if(M != null && M(a, b) == 15)
{
    lable1.Text = " Hi";
}
```

After your update, it get's a bit more complicated:

```
Func<int, int, int> M = null;
Func<int, int, int> N = null;
Func<int, int, int> K = null;
if(c == 6)
{ 
    M = (x, y) => x * y; 
}
if(c == 7)
{ 
    M = (x, y) => x / y; 
}
// Similar initialization if N and K

if(M == null || N == null || K == null)
    return;

if(K(N(M(a, b), c), d) == 25)
{
    lable1.Text = " Hi";
}
```

**But this is getting ridiculous...**
I think it would be better to use a mathematical parser.

Comment: i wil try that, if anyone have another idea please post it :)

Answer (score 10):

```
    Func<int, int, int> M/* = null; ??*/;
    switch (c)
    {
        case 6:
            M = (i,j) => i*j;
            break;
        case 7:
            M = (i,j) => i/j;
            break;
    }

    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;

    if (15 == M(a,b))
                  lable1.Text = " Hi";
```

**You need a default initialisation for the action**, I'll leave that to your imagination

Comment: I suppose with jony probably being new to C# using a func is kind of mean, but of course this would work.

Comment: Well, isn't that what he asked?

Comment: +1 for using `Func` and a `switch`, but you do not need a default value for the `Func`, a `null` is enough.

Comment: @codymanix: _var_ cannot be used in this context, let alone this example. @Blindy: you absolutely need a default, or you need to null-check it before invocation. As written, the compiler won't accept it (with good reason)

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
int result;
if(c == 6) 
  { result=a*b; } 
else if(c == 7) 
  { result = a/b} 

if( result == 15) { lable1.Text = "Hi"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this.

```
var calc = 0;
if(c == 6)
{ 
    calc = a * c; 
}
else
{
    if(c == 7)
    { 
        calc = a / c;
    }
}
if( calc == 15 )
{
    lable1.Text = " Hi";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: let me explain my self, i want to have a command line like
if(a M b N c K d == 25)
{
lable1.Text = "hi";
}
and a b c d are numbers that changes with 'for'
and M N K are strings of Mathematical operation that also change with 'for'
and every time the program checks if a M b N c K d == 25...

Answer (score 0):

yet another way:

```
Dictionaty<int,Func<int,int,int>> operations = new Dictionaty<int,Func<int,int,int>>();
operations.Add(6, (x,y) => x*y);
operations.Add(7, (x,y) => x/y);
... 
var result = operations[c](a,b);
```

you can define the dictionary in a [static] constructor for example

-edit-

after reading your edit it sounds like you're really looking for a constraint solver, a program that given a number of variables and a number of constraints, finds a solution. perhaps you should check out [Z3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/) or [SolverFoundation](http://www.solverfoundation.com/) or another [SMT solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMT_solver) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for having syntax to write an infix operator like `a M b` that is impossible in C#.

It's not possible to define new operators known at compile time, let alone variable operators.  You'll need to look into code generation or essentially string parsing.  I think maybe Haskell or some functional languages may allow you to do create that syntax (Maybe F#?), but I'm pretty sure what you're asking is not possible in C#